# How to print a variable having non-English characters to the command prompt using Python

Tags: python, unicode, non-english

I have a python program that generates a string in Tamil language. For example, the string could be தமிழ் . I could write this exactly as it appears here to a text file by using utf-8 at the time of opening the file. But when I write the same string variable to stdout using print() function it displays 3 what(?) characters surrounded by boxes. I have seen printing of literals like print(b'\xc2\xb5'.decode()) and print (u'\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f') happening properly. But the issue arises when I try to print to stdout a text string variable like this. How can I solve this problem? My platform is Windows 10.

Comment: I don't think this is a Python issue. It probably relates to what your terminal application will support.

Comment: thx for the response. but the terminal is correctly displaying the string literals (examples in my question) of that kind when printed from within the same python program.

Comment: Please can you write in the question the exact statement that is not working. I can do `print('தமிழ்')` and it works.

Comment: It could be that the font your terminal is using does not support Tamil characters.

Comment: In my system if I add the code print('தமிழ்') it shows ? printed 5 times in the command terminal. But if I copy these 5 ?'s and paste it in notepad it displays தமிழ் properly.

Comment: print('தமிழ்') is not working. also, tam = 'தமிழ்' and print(tam) is also not working ; 
but the following 2 cases work:- 
print((b'\xc2\xb5').decode())
print (u'\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f') . 
I have checked with Lucida console and Consolas as default fonts in command shell window. Consolas shows properly for the last two cases ONLY but not for the tamil word 'தமிழ்'.

Comment: I checked with the Hindi word 'हिंदी' too. It gives the same problem. May be it is terminal problem. I am not sure which font for the windows terminal can display Indian language alphabets properly.

Comment: Could you tell me what is the font setting for your command shell in your machine.? (you get this by right clicking the top of the command window and selecting properties and then Font tab)

Comment: If it works with escape sequences, but not with literal Tamil characters, it sounds a lot like your source file is not encoded properly. Make sure the file is encoded with UTF-8 (should be a save option by your editor/IDE). If you are still using Python 2, you need to add the `# coding: utf8` declaration at the top of your script.

Comment: I have used notepad for the python code and the Encoding is UTF-8 in the Save file option. As 'alani' has said it could be terminal issue. I came across an article at the URL:-   ( https://www.thewindowsclub.com/add-custom-fonts-to-command-prompt ), where the author shows how to add a custom font to windows terminal. The tamil or any indian language fonts are not getting added by that procedure. I am trying to find out which monospace-truetype font that can display indian languages is accepted by windows for command terminal.

Comment: I looked for alternatives to windows command shell and got 2 good alternatives: cmder and consoleZ . They display the tamil and other languages too in the output of my python code.

Comment: The _Cascadia Mono_ font used by default in [Windows terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-settings#text-settings) renders _Tamil_ characters smoothly.

Comment: I just now tried Cascadia Mono font with proper settings in registry editor. Even it's not rendering tamil characters on my machine. Don't know why. I came across a new Windows Terminal from microsoft (released last year and available in microsoft store) and installed it. It displays tamil font properly in it. Also, i just now tried in PyCharm. Here too it displays tamil words properly in its output terminal. So, at least i have many alternatives now.

Comment: Strangely enough, the _Cascadia Mono_ font does not render Tamil characters in pure `cmd` window…

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `Region & Language Settings` via the Search Bar and add the Tamil language.  Below I have added Chinese as an example because I am studying it:

[image: Languages section of Settings]

2. Open a terminal and make sure your language is selected in the language bar:

[image: Language selection in notification area]

3. Open the "Command Prompt" properties and make sure to select one of the new fonts that should appear to support your language.

[image: Command prompt Properties]

4. Type something in the language to test it:

[image: command prompt example]