# How do I print Hebrew output in python interpreter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using file paths and some of my directories and files are in Hebrew, and when I print it in python interpreter it prints question marks: [image: screenshot] (I can't copy the signs since when I copy it to here it's being pasted as a normal Hebrew text). My main issue is that in other languages and signs it does work, for example:

```
>>> word = 'πάπια'
>>> word
'πάπια'
```

But specifically in Hebrew it doesn't, so I couldn't find anything helpful on the internet. I'm using windows 10, python 3.8 interpreter and the default font is cp1252.
I tried:

```
>>> print(u'שבלול')
שבלול
```

and

```
>>> word = 'שבלול'
>>> word
'שבלול'
>>> enc_word = word.encode('UTF-8')
>>> enc_word
b'\xd7\xa9\xd7\x91\xd7\x9c\xd7\x95\xd7\x9c'
>>> enc_word.decode('UTF-8')
'שבלול'
```

And both doesn't actually work - in the interpreter it always prints the same question marks.

Comment: If it looks right after copying and pasting it, it's probably the fault of your terminal or lack of support in the font that it's using. So please edit your question with more information about those two.

Comment: To be clear with what Thomas is saying, this is probably unrelated to Python. It looks like you're using the Windows Console, so you'd probably get the same question marks if you used CMD, PowerShell, etc. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Let us know which operating system and `import locale;print(local.getpreferredencoding())` is. If windows, check out the new [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701#activetab=pivot:overviewtab) which is rumored to have better utf-8 support.

Comment: It's a font problem, but being a right-to-left language you will need to install Hebrew language support on Windows.  Or use an IDE with good UTF-8 and RTL language support instead of the console, such as Jupyter Notebook

Comment: @Mark Tolonen it's not a problem in Jupyter Notebook, pyCharm and other IDEs, but when I run things in the interpreter myself the problem pops up.

Comment: As I said, to work in the console you need to install Hebrew language support on Windows *OR* use an IDE.  I haven't personally installed Hebrew, but I've installed Chinese support and can read and write Chinese in the console just fine.

Comment: Here's instructions to update language support: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63893448/235698